# Core Data Single Managed Object Context and two threads

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am going crazy trying to figure this out. I am working on an application that is syncing up data from the webserver. There is a background thread that is pulling data from the server to the application. At the same time I am making changes to the UI. The values changed on UI are being saved to core data in foreground.

Through out the application I have one managedObjectContext that I fetch from the app delegate every time I create a fetchController . App delegate code

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

Now the problem is I am getting error while trying to save the context. The errors are happening randomly in the code. I am saving the context as soon as I am making change to any entity. Also I have two relationships each in each entity one to its child that is one to many and one to its parents that is to - one. All relationship have appropriate inverse.

I think I am doing something conceptually wrong over here by mentaining one context. Could you please advice how I should manage context in a  situation where both background and foreground threads are reading and writing to the coredata. Thanks.

Comment: You are using initializing your MOC with thread confinement, so you must only use it on the thread that created it... most likely the main thread.  There is nothing inherently wrong with it... but how are you creating the MOC for your background saving?  If you are using the same MOC that's your problem.  Read the documentation on Concurrency with Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed object contexts are not thread safe, so if you use the same one on more than one thread without considering concurrency-- you're going to have major problems. As in, crashing and/or data loss and maybe even data corruption. There are a couple of ways to deal with this:

1. Use one of the queue concurrency types when creating the context-- see docs for `initWithConcurrencyType:`. Then, whenever you access the data store, use either `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` to synchronize access.
2. Create a new managed object context for the background thread. Use `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` to keep multiple contexts synchronized.

But whatever you do, do **not** just use one managed object context on more than one thread.